# Is autocorrelation and the number of clusters related in an ergodic process

Tags: dynamical-systems, markov-chains

I' ve come across two notions for the condition of (mean-) ergodicity and wonder whether and how they relate.

(1) Let $ {X}_{t \ge 0} $ be a second order stationary process with (constant) mean $\mu$ and autocorrelation function $R(t)$. If $ R(t) \in L^1(0,\infty ) $
then
$$ lim_{T \to \infty} \Bbb E \ \bigg| { 1\over T} \int_{0}^{T} (X(s)-\mu) ds \ \bigg|^2=0$$

This result is intuitive: For $R(t)$ to be in $L^1(0,\infty)$, $R(t)$ needs to fall off quickly. As a result, the process 'loses' memory quickly and forgets its initial value and keeps starting all over again and again. As a result, the process is ergodic.

(2) For a homogeneous Markov chain define operators $P_t$ via
$$ P_t f(x) = \Bbb E \left( f(X_t) \vert X_0=x \right) $$
for suitable real-valued functions $f$ acting in the state-space of the Markov-chain.
Then $X_t$ is ergodic if
$$ P_t g=g$$ only admits constant solutions.In other words, the dimension of the eigenspace with eigenvalue 1 is one-dimensional.

Also, this result is intuitive since the dimension of this eigenstate corresponds to the number of clusters in the state-space: Whereas the dynamics of a particular path take place in a specific cluster only, it cannot generally agree with the expectation value since it averages over all clusters. Hence ergodicity implies one cluster only.(What about if one played devil's advocate and for some reason the averages in each clusters are the same?)

What puzzles me is whether the two conditions are related and if so how.